# Problem deleting parts / frame of polygons / shape

Tags: qgis

I generated a polygon-layer from a raster dataset. the extensions of the raster are now shown as a frame. When I delete this and save it is there again (pls see attached images): 1st image how it looks before deleting frame and after saving, 2nd image how it should look like. Can anyone help me on this???

[image: wrong]

[image: right]

Comment: Just in case, did you save your edits before saving the layer?

Comment: Any warning or error message after saving?

Comment: @ Oto Kaláb: Yes, I did.

Comment: @ Artwork 21: No warings ...

Comment: What happens if select all features except for that one and do a save as to new shapefile?

Comment: I just calculated the area and than deleted the biggest area within the attribute table. That  worked, why ever :)

Comment: just found out that I was wrong. I can save the new layer but if I open again the old style appears. I also tried artworks suggestion but it also doesn`t work. I start to become desperate... :(